# nuxt 3 index page throws a 404

Tags: nuxtjs3

I'm playing around with nuxt and I'm running into an issue, when I run it in dev mode, the home page never loads up, it throws a 404, if I go to localhost:3000/index it will *then* load, which is not at all what I expect. Their docs state that if you name the file index.vue it'll make it the root page but it doesn't seem to for me and wondering if someone can help me figure out what I may doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error shows, the configuration is incorrect.

In the root file there is a `app.vue` which is a default when you create a nuxt app boiler plate.

In the `app.vue`, add these lines of codes.

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <NuxtPage />
  </div>
</template>
```

Adding page/pages.

1. Create a `pages` folder in your root directory .
2. Inside the `pages` folder, create an `index.vue` file.
3. The `index.vue` will be your default/home page.

`~/pages/index.vue`

```js
<template>
    <div>Hello World</div>
</template>
```

Now, when you run it, it will show the 'Hello World'.

More information about the pages folder
https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/pages

Working example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-vxsvtp?file=pages/index.vue

Comment: I see my problem, dummy me named the file Index.vue, it has to be a lowercase i.